# I am getting an error only on Safari Browser when executing a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, safari

on my webiste which is a little guessing game I am getting an error on only the Safari Browser when executing a function and I don't know why.

The error is the following message:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.
(anonymus function)
(rejectPromise)

here is the function:

```
$("#repeat_btn").addClass("repeat_hover");
    
    if (diff_lvl == 1) {
        $.post('played_games.php?diff=1', {game:"voice",post_id:<?php echo $usr_id; ?>}, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        });                                       
    } else if (diff_lvl == 3) {
        $.post('played_games.php?diff=3', {game:"voice",post_id:<?php echo $usr_id; ?>}, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }); 
    }
    
    var count = array_voices_hashes.length;

    var newpic_onload = Math.floor((Math.random() * count) + 0);
    
    var randompic_onload = array_voices_hashes[newpic_onload];
    document.getElementById("voice").src = 'sounds/' + randompic_onload + '.ogg';
    
    document.getElementById("voice").play();
    cdreset();
    countdown();
```

Does anyone know what creates the error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it might be due to security policy to start audio by user action first. Try to let user click on something first when they first open the website. Attach all the necessary audio files. Play it, immedietely stop it and after this you should be able to play the audio files automatically from script. You need to know your sources beforehand thought. I would suggest listing all audio files as html5 tags that you reference by id in your script.

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { if(audiosWeWantToUnlock)
{  for(let audio of audiosWeWantToUnlock) {
   audio.play()
   audio.pause()
   audio.currentTime = 0  }  audiosWeWantToUnlock = null}}, false)
```